# how can display a qr in a window modal?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

I have this function that returns a value to display a qr

```
def some():
return http.request.render('as_website_sale_onepage.cria', {
    'QRimage':orders.qrImage,
            })
```

it displays in that section

```
<div>
<img if="QRimage" t-att-src="'data:image/jpg;base64,'+ QRimage" alt="QrCode" />
</div>
```

the result is this
[QR image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ovP4.png)

how can i display that in a modal window?

Comment: A modal is html too. So what is the specific problem in inserting the same in another section of your html?

Comment: I want to display that in a pop up window or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modal from W3School [W3School: How To Make a Modal Box With CSS and JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ovP4.png" alt="Qr Code" />
  </div>

</div>
```